# Sould I denormalize(merge) 2 similar but not identical tables or keep them separate?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have entries in a database that contain members.

- Member can be an adult or a child.
- There is 30 columns for each member.
- Out of these there's 7 exclusive columns for adults and 7 for children(coincidence - it may be e.g. 7 and 8 later). 23 columns are identical.

Currently these are in 2 tables. Would it be a good design decision to merge(denormalize) these tables or to keep them separate?

In my case writing is not so important. Complexity related to reading is.

If I merge them there'll be at least 7 empty fields in each record. But then I'll be able to seamlessly tranform child to adult and won't have any issues with relations(e.g. where member belongs to category, building, event) because member's id will always be unique.

Comment: You need three tables: `persons` or `members` with common columns. `adults` and `children` with the "exclusive" columns and a foreign key to `persons`.

Comment: I suggest you flip a coin.  Then, a few months from now, decide whether to switch to the other schema.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks, I wanted to avoid creating unnecessary relationships but this solution seems to be most optimal.

Comment: @RickJames but then how will I know that the other one is better or at least not worse? Actually, this is a situation I'm in right now :).

Comment: "Better" -- They won't be much different.  There are only slight advantages for one; slight advantages for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Given your circumstances, I would merge them. The pros are simpler code with fewer joins. There might be a small hit due to storage, but I would consider it negligible.